# Can more profitable firms raise more capital in external markets, or only by retained earnings?

Tags: capital-structure

When thinking about capital and scale I usually think of capital like any other input, where you can buy all you want as a pure price taker. But I think firms are actually able to raise more capital if they either offer a higher rate of return or provide evidence of higher profitability.

However, I don't see how to make this intuition consistantwith the reality that pretty much all firms are small relative to the size of the capital market.

I see that firms could raise more capital via internal markets in the advantageous circumstances described above. Is that the only way to do it? Or is it also possible to raise more capital externally in these settings? If so, how is this harmonized with a large capital market? Through market segmentation, maybe?

Side question: Where should I look for data on the share of its capital an average firm raises through borrowing vs retained earnings? (Ideally by industry).